# Opening a popup with Alchemy4Tridion framework

Tags: gui-extensions, a4t

I'm creating a GUI Extension with the Alchemy4Tridion framework and want to open a popup.  The problem is the popup file is installed in `assets/popup.html` by Alchemyand not `assets/views/popup.html`.  How do I get the file to be deployed to the `/assets/views/` folder?

My file structure is `/Static/Scripts/Command.js` and `/Static/Views/popup.html`.  In the `Views` folder I have a `popup.html` file.

In my `ResourceGroup.cs` file I have the following:

```cs
   AttachToView("popup.html");
   Dependencies.AddAlchemyCore();
```

In the `Commands.js` file, execute function I use the following to open the popup:

```cs
 var itemId = selection.getItem(0);
 var url = "${ViewsUrl}popup.html?item=" + itemId,
 popup = $popup.create(url, "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,width=405,height=180", null);
 popup.open();
```

Comment: Not sure if it`s a problem for your requirements, but I wrote a quick article on reusing a popup for an A4T Command.js otherwise if you click the button that opens a popup, you get a new one every time you click the button. http://tridionted.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/opening-popup-with-alchemy4tridion.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that Alchemy does not yet pick up HTML files. Try creating it as an ASPX file instead. Static HTML files are often cached a little too aggressively by the browsers anyway, so you might want to avoid them in any case if you plan to do anything dynamic in it.